# Conditions not satifies in pattern, still processing is being executed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Using XSL, I am trying to select data based on XML node attribute id. I am using a  "for-each" loop due to in later stage I will search for "period" or "balance".

**Problem:** Even though I intentionally change the pattern, the processing still executes.

Here is startpoint of my code: http://xsltransform.net/3NqnAET/3

If I change:

from: `<xsl:for-each select="xbrli:context/@id='period0'">`

to: `<xsl:for-each select="xbrli:context/@id='period1'">`

I expect the body in result to be empty due to the match criterias are not fulfilled.

See change here: http://xsltransform.net/3NqnAET/4

Comment: You are iterating over a boolean value,  I guess you want the condition in a predicate in square brackets.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. I missed to embed the predicat within square brackets. This select works correct: "/xbrli:xbrl[xbrli:context/@id='period1']"